# How to extract data using JMeter and AMQP Consumer?

Tags: jmeter, rabbitmq, amqp

i am using plugin [JMeter-Rabbit-AMQP](https://github.com/jlavallee/JMeter-Rabbit-AMQP). I don't understand how to extract data from consumer. I publish, and a response is returned to another queue that my consumer is subscribed to. I don't understand how I can get this answer and continue the test with the logic of this answer

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a suitable [JMeter Post Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) as a child of the consumer sampler and configure it to extract the desired part of the response.

If you want the full response - add [Boundary Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-boundary-extractor-vs-the-regular-expression-extractor-in-jmeter) and leave left and right boundaries empty.

[image]

Once done you will be able to access the extracted response as `${response}` [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) where required

Comment: It`s not work( [Traceback](https://ibb.co/G3gt7RT)

Comment: it is work, it is your consumer who is not to work because your message is not to have header therefore you is to have a null pointer exception\